# active directory dssite subnet for client natted network

Tags: active-directory

I have an infra that has 3 networks: A, B, C :

- A can see B directly, but can only see C by its natted network (for ex: the natted network is D)
- B can see both A and C directly
- C can see A directly.

In general, C is natted from the point of view of A.

Now I have 2 DC servers, one in network A and one in B, and only member servers in the network C.

I'm going to define 2 AD sites, one site contains the DC in network A, another has the DC in the network B.

And I plan to add network C to the AD site where has network B.

But I would like to have your advise that which subnet I should declare for C ? It's real network C or its natted network D ? Or both ?

Thanks

Copdips

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting them up based on the bandwidth and latency of the subnets, if the NAT'ing is not effecting that (the firewall or whatever is not a bottleneck and you have good throughput) it should be in the same Site as the un-NAT'ed stuff that is co-located with it.

I personally would create two sites with a very low cost link between them just to make it clear which side of the NAT clients were coming from. That way you can use Site based GPOs for network related settings.

All of this is probably a moot point though - your DC's should work most of this out on their own and setting up Sites is usually only needed for very complex topologies.

Edit: Add both the NAT and actual subnet of the clients to the same (new) site  (C in your case). That way they know which resources (DCs etc) are local irreguardless of which IP the server's see them using. IP's don't really matter except as far as that's how AD determines what is where,

Comment: Hi TheFIddlerWins, thanks for your comments. In fact the 3 networks A,B,C are in there seprate cities. As C is natted from point of view of A. That's why I would like to create two site, one for A, one for B and C. But don't know which subnet to bind to the second site for network C ? it's real network C or it's natted network D ? thx.